# Jest override manual mock override with doMock not work

Tags: mocking, jestjs

I have a manual mock in the `__mocks__` folder.  In the root of my test file I do the fillowing in order to mock the specific module

```
jest.mock('./apiClientToMock')
```

This works fine and jest picks up the manual mock.

Now in one of the tests I want to override this manual mock and return a specific value.  To that end I do the following

```
describe('test', ()=>{
    beforeEach(() => {
        jest.doMock('./apiClientToMock', () => {
          //Implementation
        }
    }); 
})});
```

However jest always seem to pick up my manual mock in the `__mocks__` folder.  Jet does not even seem to call the code insider the doMock part. 
 How do I fix this.  Whats more if I remove the manual mock then it picks up the doMock, but says method is not defined.  Plus if I move the doMock to the top and use just `mock` then it seem to work fine.